# pip version error on cli

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip

I am getting below error on installing aws via pip. I am using the latest version of python. Any reason to this?

Command used for this `pip install awscli`

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement awscli 
(from versions: )
No matching distribution found for awscli
```

Comment: What command are you running? What operating system are you using?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have updated my question with command used.

Comment: Latest version of python 3? and is this on Linux?

Comment: @Harlekuin python 2.7.10. Using Mac

Comment: You might have to use `sudo pip install awscli` but versions and locations become a hassle. Works best if you use a `virtualenv` and install into there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest version of pip.

Also make sure that you use the right version of python for installation

> The aws-cli package works on Python versions:
>
> - 2.6.5 and greater
> - 2.7.x and greater
> - 3.3.x and greater
> - 3.4.x and greater
> - 3.5.x and greater
> - 3.6.x and greater

To choose a python version for install append the version to "pip" command like so: `pip3.6 install awscli`.